# Exam paper in A3 booklet format

Tags: geometry, exam

I use the exam class for my tests. I usually give them in a booklet format which is the folded version of A3 paper. Here is a sample 4-page test:

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 10pt, a4paper]{exam}

%\usepackage[a3paper, landscape, twocolumn]{geometry}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\footer{}{Page \thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}{}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{\begin{center}
Sample Test
\end{center}}{}{}
\runningheader{\begin{center}
Sample Test
\end{center}}{}{}
\gradetable[h]

\begin{questions}
\question[25]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figs/test.eps} 
\end{figure}
\newpage
\question[25]
\newpage
\question[25]
\newpage
\question[25]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

When the geometry line uncommented, what I expect is this:

[image: this].

But the page footer does not align and it looks like it's 2-page. More importantly, the page order is not in correct order (4,1,2,3) for booklet format.

How I prepared the A3 booklet by now is quite impractical. After I compiled the test pdf in A4, passed it to PDFLaTeX like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={4,1},nup=2x1]{test.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={2,3},nup=2x1]{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can do this directly in my document?

Comment: Unrelated to LaTeX but as a teacher i'm always using this format for my lessons/tests/exams. Many printers are able to print a booklet format on A3 page paper without any changes on a pdf file. You can simply set the option on the printer directly and function of the numbers of pages, the printers will organize the pages automatically. Apart from a printer, you can also launch a booklet format from a computer by setting the corresponding option too without any changes on your pdf.

Comment: @Piroooh, thank you for the advise. However, printer options might be restricted by the company/school.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the booklet package.  Removing the [print] option will format normally.

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 10pt, a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[twouparticle,print]{booklet}
\source{\magstep0}{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}
\target{\magstep0}{2\paperwidth}{\paperheight}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\AtBeginDocument{\setpdftargetpages}% pdflatex
\AtBeginDocument{\setdvipstargetpages}% otherwise

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\footer{}{Page \thepage{} / \pageref{LastPage}}{}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{}{Sample Test}{}
\runningheader{}{Sample Test}{}

\begin{document}
\gradetable[h]

\begin{questions}
\question[25]\lipsum[1]
\fullwidth{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}}
\newpage
\question[25]
\newpage
\question[25]
\newpage
\question[25]
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This creates just a 2 page pdf with the page numbers Page4/4 and Page 2/2.

Comment: Are you using pdflatex?  Otherwise use \setdvitargetpages instead.

Comment: Looking at the aux file I see that \thepage is never being expanded.  So \pageref will always return the current page number.  The manual says to not use [print] until the last run.

Comment: I use the LaTeX-dvips-ps2pdf structure.  \setdvitargetpages gives the "! Undefined control sequence." error by the way. Still no luck for me.

Comment: Oops, \setdvipstargetpages.  I tested it this time.

Comment: Getting better. It works! But when I used \usepackage{graphicx} and wanted to include some graphics, it turns back to normal form from the booklet form. Didn't undertand that.

Comment: It has something to so with \magstep.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374966/package-conflict-booklet-and-graphicx

Comment: In retrospect, the approach isn't any easier than using pdfpages.  Its only advantage is that it uses only one LaTeX source file.